# How to estimate the size of the neighborhoods in the Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, inverse

Given a function $f:U \subset V\to W$ such that $\textbf{D}f(x_0)\neq 0$ for some $x_0$. How to estimate the neighborhood for which it's invertible? 
Assuming the second derivative exists and is continuous.

Comment: As a general rule, if a mathematical theorem promises you existence of some object, such as a neighborhood in which some function is invertible, without any further comment, then it promises exactly that and no more. That is, the promised neighborhood can be arbitrarily small, or arbitrarily big, so no general estimate is available. In special cases, where you have information on your function, you can investigate further.

Comment: Actually, just about any proof of the inverse function theorem will give you a lower bound on the size of a neighborhood on which it's invertible, if you just follow the proof and keep careful track of the way the various $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s are chosen. I think you can derive an estimate in terms of upper bounds on $|Df(x)|$ and $|Df(x)^{-1}|$ for $x$ near $x_0$.

Answer (score 8):

This kind of estimate is rarely needed, but in fact, sometimes one would like to know this.

One estimate of the type you are looking for can be found in Serge Langs Real Analysis (which is, in my opinion, a highly underestimated book on Real analysis), 2nd edition, Chapter 6 §1 Lemma 1.3. It depends on a continuity estimate for $f^\prime$, which you may or may not get from the assumed continuity of the second derivative (depends on what exactly you do know about $d^2 f$...).

*Edit* this is the same lemma as in Lang's Real and Functional Analysis, Chapter XIV, §1, Lemma 1.3, if you cannot get hold of the Real Analysis.