# Does an injective map stay injective under small smooth perturbations?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M,N$ be smooth two-dimensional connected, oriented, compact Riemannian manifolds with boundaries, and let $f:M \to N$ be smooth and **injective**.

> Let $f_t:M \to N$ be a smooth variation of $f$. Is $f_t$ injective for sufficiently small $t$?

If that matters, I am fine with assuming that $\det(df)>0$ and $f(\partial M) \subseteq \partial N$. (although I am not sure if it's needed.)

Here is a naive attempt: Suppose that this is not so; then we have $t_n \to 0$, $x_n \neq y_n 
\in M$ such that $f_{t_n}(x_n)=f_{t_n}(y_n)$. Since $M$ is compact we have $x_n \to x,y_n \to y$ (modulue subsequences). Thus $f(x)=f(y)$. Since $f$ is injective, this forces $x=y$.

So, $x_n \neq y_n, x_n,y_n \to x$ and $f_{t_n}(x_n)=f_{t_n}(y_n)$. Now, if $x \in N^o$, then $f(x) \in M^o$ (since $df_x$ is non-singular), so by the inverse function theorem, applied to $f_t|_{M^o}:M^o \to N^o$ at $x$, $f_t$ is injective in a neighbourhood of $x$. This might be contradictory with $x_n,y_n \to x$, if we can quantify the size of the neighbourhood where the IFT gives us injectivity, independently of $t$ for small $t$. (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469199/how-to-estimate-the-size-of-the-neighborhoods-in-the-inverse-function-theorem)). A similar argument should work when $x \in \partial M$.

> Can this approach work? Are there other approaches? Or is there a counter-example?

Comment: I think this type of argument appears in the **Homotopy and Stability** of immersion, submersion, local diffeomorphism, embedding, etc.

Comment: If $M$ is compact, and $f$ is an immersion, then $f$ is a proper map, and hence an embedding. Embeddings are stable maps by transversality. Hence yes, any small perturbation will be injective.

Comment: @Daniel But this argument is part of that proof.

Comment: @TedShifrin, It was a response to the OP's first question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a standard trick for dealing with this. If your parameter $t$ is in some interval $I$, consider $F\colon M\times I\to N\times I$ given by
$$F(x,t) = (f_t(x),t).$$
Assuming that $f=f_0$ is an immersion, we see that $F$ is an immersion at $(x,0)$ for all $x\in M$, and hence one-to-one in a neighborhood of $(x,0)$. Therefore, for large enough $n$, $F(x_n,t_n)=F(y_n,t_n)$ forces $x_n=y_n$, completing your contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! nice argument. I think that it works as is only when $x \notin \partial M$ though. If we assume that $f_t(\partial M) \subseteq \partial N$ then we  can run the argument for the restriction $f_t|_{\partial M}: \partial M \to \partial N$ and conclude they are injective for small $t$. I am not sure if your argument adapts to the case where we don't assume that $f_t(\partial M) \subseteq \partial N$.

Comment: I admit I usually don't think about the boundary case. But we need immersiveness, so I don't think your worries can come to fruition.

Answer (score 2):

I will say the requirement that $f$ an immersion cant be dropped. Consider the function, $$f(x)=(x^{2},x^{3}).$$ We can consider this as a function from $[-k,k]$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, and it's injective. Now consider the smooth map
$$F(x,t)=(x^{2}-t,(x^{2}-t)x)$$

$F(x,0)=f$, but F(x,t) for t>0 is not injective.