# Is this result true? Uniform convergence and inverses

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables, inverse-function-theorem

Running through some geometry papers, I found some authors use the following idea:

Let $f_n : \Bbb C^m \to \Bbb C^m$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions converging uniformly to $f : \Bbb C^m \to \Bbb C^m$ on compact sets. Suppose $f(0) =0$ and $\frac{\partial f }{\partial z}$ is invertible (ie, the inverse function theorem can be applied). Then for any $\varepsilon >0$ there is some $N$ and a point $z \in \Bbb C^m$ such that $f_N(z)=0$ and $|z|< \varepsilon$.

I know the result is true for $m=1$, it just comes as a consequence of the argument principle, but I of course I cannot generalize to more dimensions. On top of that I have seen the problem for $m=1$ in some complex analysis books or lecture notes, which makes me think that the result exchanging $\Bbb C$ by $\Bbb R$ (and holomorphic by smooth or analytic) may not be true, which is problematic because it means that the theory of several complex variables is needed, something I am not very familiar with.

Is the result true? References or direct proofs? Are there related results? Is is true for $\Bbb R $ instead of $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Should the convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ be uniform on compact sets?

If so, this feels intuitively true. Also, this seems like a real-dimensional problem where it's still true even if you just consider $f_n$ as a function on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to prove this result using the fact that if $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compact sets, then $\partial_i f_n\to \partial_i f$ uniformly on compact sets for every multi-index $i$, which is a consequence of Cauchy's estimates.

Comment: @Eric yes, its uniform convergence; but still cannot find a proof

Comment: @Pelota is it, though? The inverse function theorem does not give bounds on the domains in which the inverses are defined, so I face the problem that these sets shrink to $0$

Comment: The inverse function theorem does give bounds on the domains in which the inverses are defined (depending on bounds on $Jf$ obviously), see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469199/how-to-estimate-the-size-of-the-neighborhoods-in-the-inverse-function-theorem)

Comment: It doesn't work on $\Bbb{R}^n$ try with $f(z)=z, f_N(z)=z+i/N$, but it works if $f,f_N$ are real valued and $\nabla f$ are continuous and $\nabla f_N$ converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say maximum modulus principle:

For $\epsilon>0$ fixed small enough, such that $|f|$ is non-zero on $|z|=\epsilon$ and $\det(\nabla f(z))$ is non-zero on $|z|\le \epsilon$.

For $N$ large enough and $|z|<\epsilon$,

$\det(\nabla f_N(z))$ is non-zero (being close to $\det(\nabla f(z))$).

(this was the only steps where I'm using that the functions are holomorphic, so that the derivatives are continuous and converge uniformly)

If $f_N(z)\ne 0$ then there is a direction $v=v(z,N)$ such that the directional derivative is $D_vf_N(z)= -f_N(z)$ ie. $f_N(z+hv) = f_N(z)-h f_N(z)+O(h^2)$ and thus $z$ is not a local minimum of $|f_N|$.

$\inf_{|z|\le \epsilon} |f_N(z)|$ can't be on $|z|=\epsilon$ since $|f_N|$ converges uniformly to $|f|$.

Whence there is some $|z|<\epsilon$ where $f_N(z)=0$.